# How to authorise jwt token on client side PrivateRoute?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-router, jwt, authorization

I am trying to send a simple GET request to the authorisation end point on the back end to verify the user jwt token that is held in localStorage after authenticating (logging in) successfully. I have set up a helper function (see below) that will make a GET request to the server with the jwt token in the header, if a status 200 is received then I return true (authorised).

This helper function is called within my PrivateRoute HOC and if true will return the private component and if false will redirect to Login.

Basically I can get the protected routes working if I simply just decode the token and verify that the token exists and therefore the user has logged in. However this is not checking the token against the server jwt verify and hence is not secure. I am not sure whether I need to implement asynchronous code anywhere? I know the verification step has to exist in the back end and the front end should simply send the API request with the token in the header but I cannot seem to get this work with Private Routes.

I have also tried running the helper function on the main App component as a useEffect hook, and updating a "loggedIn" state variable based on whether the helper function returns authorised or not, which could then be passed as props into other Components. I have done this for my Nav Bar component to either show "SIGN IN / REGISTER" or "SIGN OUT" based on whether the "loggedIn" state is true or false.

Server-side verify token function:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send('Access Denied');

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid Token');
    }
}
```

Helper function:

```
import React from 'react';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const checkAuth = {
        isAuthorised: false,
        userID: void (0),

        authorise: function () {

            const token = window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
            if (!token) {
                console.log('Invalid Token');
                window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", null);
            }

            const response = axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/verify',
                headers: { 'auth-token': token }
            })
            const data = response.data;
            if (response.status === 200) {
                this.isAuthorised = true;
                this.userID = data._id;
                return this.isAuthorised;
            }

            return this.isAuthorised;
        },
        logout: function () {
            window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", null);
            this.isAuthorised = false;
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        },
    }

    export default checkAuth;
```

Private Route HOC:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import checkAuth from './helper';

    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                checkAuth.authorise()
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
            }
        />
    );
        }
    export default PrivateRoute;
```

App Component (hiding imports):

```
const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const verify = () => {
    if (checkAuth.authorise()) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setUser(checkAuth.userID);
      console.log('logged in');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in');
      return false;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    verify()
  }, [loggedIn]);

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar loggedIn={loggedIn} user={user} />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/story" component={Story} />
          <Route path="/prologue" component={Prologue} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/chapters" component={Chapters} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/forum" component={Forum} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/characters" component={Characters} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/characters/:id" component={CharacterSheet} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar Component (only relevant part):

```
const NavBar = ({ loggedIn, user }) => {
    return (
      ...
          {loggedIn ? (
                    <Nav>
                        <h1 style={{ paddingRight: '30px', color: 'black', fontSize: '32pt'}}>Welcome, {user}</h1>
                        <Nav.Link href="/" onClick={() => checkAuth.logout()}>Sign Out</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                ) : (
                        <Nav>
                            <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/register">Register</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    )}
                ...
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

I would expect that when the user logs in, the NavBar would update to show user logged in based on the authorisation helper function being called as a result of the useEffect hook.

I would also expect that when a user routes to one of the protected routes (PrivateRoute), the helper function would run and return true (after login) and subsequently render.

I get my expected results when the following code is used in place of the API call in the helper function (however this is NOT correct authorisation as I understand):

```
    authorise: function () {

        const token = window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        if (!token) {
            console.log('Invalid Token');
            window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", "");
        }

        try {
            const decoded = decode(token);
            console.log(decoded)
            if (decoded) {
                this.isAuthorised = true;
                this.userID = decoded._id;
                return this.isAuthorised;
            }
        }
        catch {
            console.log('invalid token')
        }

        return this.isAuthorised;
    },
```

At the moment, logging in appears to do nothing - although the user token is received and stored in LocalStorage.

Answer (score 0):

axios returns a promise, so, basically, you need to change your validation code to something like this:

```
return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/verify',
    headers: { 'auth-token': token }
})
    .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        if (response.status === 200) {
            this.isAuthorised = true;
            this.userID = data._id;
        }

        return this.isAuthorised;
    });
```

And then handle `checkAuth.authorise()` call as a promise as well